# Thin server with application state

Tags: ruby, web-services, daemon, thin

I need to build a webservice with application state. By this I mean the webservice needs to load and process a lot of data before being ready to answer requests, so a Rails-like approach where normally you don't keep state at the application level between two requests doesn't look appropriate.

I was wondering if a good approach was a daemon (using [Daemon-Kit](https://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit) for instance) embedding a simple web server like Thin. The daemon would load and process the initial data.

But I feel it would be better to use Thin directly (launched with Rack). In this case how can I initialize and maintain my application state ?

**EDIT**: There will be thousands of requests per second, so having to read the app state from files or DB at each one is not efficient. I need to use global variables, and I am wondering what it the cleanest way to initialize and store then in a Ruby/Thin environment.

Comment: Are you expecting clients to use HTTP to connect to your server?

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain state a number of ways.

- A database, including NoSQL databases like Memcache or Redis
- A file, or multiple files
- Global variables or class variables, assuming the server never gets restarted/reloaded

Comment: There will be thousands of requests per second, so having to read the app state from files or DB at each one is not efficient. I need to use global variables, and I am wondering what it the cleanest way to initialize and store then in a Ruby/Thin environment.

Comment: Also, global/class variables don't work if you have multiple server instances, which if you're servicing that many requests you will certainly have.